# Entity Framework. Confuses DbProviderFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two database providers: SQL Server and MySql. EF confuses `DbProviderFactory`. EF creates my `DbContext`, and set factory mySql with SQL Server connection string!

My connection strings:

```
<add name="MsSqlConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"/>
<add name="MySqlConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=server;Database=db;Uid=user;Pwd=password;"/>
```

My contexts:

```
namespace DAL.EntityFramework.MySql
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class MySqlContext: DbContext
    {
        public MySqlContext(string connectionName) : base(nameOrConnectionString: connectionName)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeMap());
        }
    }
}

namespace DAL.EntityFramework.App
{
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
       
        public ApplicationContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeMap());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

On another project everything works, did the same

Comment: could you please add a piece of code where you pass a context to a method? do you use DI?

Comment: Yes, I use DI (Unity). I'll can add code only on monday :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best bug in my life!
Thanks to Michael, the problem was DI (Unity)!
I registered my dependency:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<MySqlContext>(new InjectionConstructor("MySqlGlobalConnectionTest"));
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationContext>(new InjectionConstructor("ApplicationConnectionTest"));
    container.RegisterType<MsSqlReadOnlyContext>(new InjectionConstructor("MsSqlApplicationConnection"));
    container.RegisterType<IUnityOfWork, UnityOfWork>();
}
```

And the problem was in the ORDER of implementation!

```
public class UnityOfWork : IUnityOfWork
    {
        private MySqlContext mySqlContext;
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        private MsSqlReadOnlyContext msSqlReadOnlyContext;

        public UnityOfWork(
             ApplicationContext applicationContext,
             MsSqlReadOnlyContext msSqlReadOnlyContext,
             MySqlContext mySqlContext // <-- When I put on the first place - there is an error of definition of factory!
            )
        {
            this.mySqlContext = mySqlContext;
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
            this.msSqlReadOnlyContext = msSqlReadOnlyContext;
        }
}
```

This is a very strange bug. Apparently some sort of issue with UnityDI